# How to divide a hypersphere in even parts with n hyperplanes

Tags: geometry

I am trying to cut an hypersphere in equal parts using n hyperplanes.

I need a way to compute the normal to those planes.

For visual purpose, this is what it should like if I was using a 2-sphere and 3 plans:

https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/atx2sgtv

P.S. I plan on using 150 planes on a 2999-sphere but I would like the general form so that i can try to change those parameters

FYI : My math knowledge is limited to 3D spaces and some basic understanding of hyperspaces coordinate systems.

Comment: What kind of "parts" are you looking for? For example, if you had just chopped a 2-sphere into two parts with a plane passing through the origin, why would that be not good enough?

Comment: Finding $n$ hyperplanes dividing in an even way the hypersphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is always possible by taking rotating planes around axis NS (north-south poles) with angles $2k \pi/n$". Do you want a kind of generalization of this "orange peels" construction ( which differs from yours) ?

Comment: I need a way to find n hyperplanes that divide an hypersphere in  Rk where k > n. And I don't want the strategy where you just cut along k axis because it will make the n - k after the k first dimensions adding no "value" in the slicing. BTW I forgot to say but the hypersphere is a unit sphere.

Comment: I need this for LSH because I need to get only one bucket Id and using random planes sample from normal distribution is not really smart for only one hyper space

Comment: My bad I meant that I don't want a strategy where you cut along n axis because it will make the k - n after the n first dimensions adding no "value" in the slicing.

Comment: 1) I wasn't aware of your answers because you hadn't use my pseudo `@Jean Marie` in front of them 2) Looking for "equal parts" rings in my ears as looking as  equivalent to the quest for regular (hyper)polyhedron inscribed in your (hyper)sphere

Comment: I was prototyping with random planes but now i would like to solve this problem. After some searching i indeed think that searching for hyperpolyhedron inscribed in the hypersphere is the best solution (@JeanMarie). Do you have any idea where i can start to search, or any revelant documentation. Thank you in advance

Comment: should i open a new post maybe ?

Comment: 1) The advantage to open a new question is that it will attract more people. 2) Is your objective still to get "orange peels" all with the same size (but looking much less elongated that what is called usually an orange peel : see our previous discussion) ? One thing is certain: for a given (hyper)-dimension there are only 3 regular polyhedra (hyperoctahedron, hypercube aka tesseract, hypertetrahedron aka simplex) ; see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope#Higher-dimensional_polytopes but nothing prevents to divide their faces...

Comment: Thank you for all your help, i have opened a new question which state the problems a little bit more clearly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451797/find-in-which-face-lie-a-point-on-a-hyper-polytope-inscribed-in-an-hyper-unit-s) @JeanMarie